# MVC 3.0 Basics - Installing MVC3.0 required on IIS Server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've mvc3.0 (.net 4.0) application that needs to be deployed to windows server 2008.

Could some one please help with my queries below?

1. Do I need to install MVC 3.0 on server if I've referenced all MVC dll (with Copy Local set to true?)
2. If I had MVC 2.0 installed on web server, does IIS picks MVC2.0 dll or MVC 3 given step 1 scenario above?
3. When does IIS looks at DLL vs. BIN folder?

Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.) Do I need to install MVC 3.0 on server if I've referenced all MVC dll (with Copy Local set to true?)

No, you could [`bin deploy`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) your application.

> 2.) If I had MVC 2.0 installed on web server, does IIS picks MVC2.0 dll or MVC 3 given step 1 scenario above?

Assuming you have placed proper [`assembly binding redirects`](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading) in your web.config It will pick MVC 3:

```
<runtime>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc"
           publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
     </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

> 3.) When does IIS looks at DLL vs. BIN folder?

When the application starts, or when first required (assuming some assemblies could be dynamically loaded at runtime).

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to install MVC 3.0 on server if I've referenced all MVC dll
> (with Copy Local set to true?)

Not Necessary. You can run an MVC application without installing MVC in your server. There is something called **deployable dependency** in Visual studio. That will publish your MVC DLLs in your bin folder when you publish it

from the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg286946.aspx) page,

> This will add assemblies (DLL files) to a Web site project or Web
> application project. When you deploy your Web site or application, the
> files are included in the deployed project. This is useful if
> applications or technologies that your project depends on are not
> already installed on the server that will host your Web project. For
> example, you can use this feature to deploy an ASP.NET MVC 3 Web
> application to a server that does not have ASP.NET MVC 3 installed.

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441568/do-i-need-to-install-mvc-3-4-on-web-server-to-run-mvc-application/10441585#10441585) answer where i have given step by step instruction how to do this.

Check this post for more details http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

You should have **Visual Studio 2010 SP1**. Otherwise it will not be shown in the context menu when you right click on the project to be published.

Answer (score 0):

1. Already asked, see - [ASP.NET MVC deployment in a form of distribution package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790184/asp-net-mvc-deployment-in-a-form-of-distribution-package)
2. it'll get exact version, which you used to build application
3. Local assembly has priority over GAC (global assembly cache)