# Distribute ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I just finished an ASP.NET MVC Application. Its a basic CRUD application that connects with a MSSQL database. Now I'm looking for ways to distribute this application (possibly MSI or EXE) where a user can just just install the application which sets up

1. The site in the local IIS.
2. Creates the database and tables for the site.
3. Creates the necessary connection with the database.

I saw a couple of similar questions but nothing that helped me. If anyone has any insight on the problem.

My wording might not be as clear so this post might make it a bit clear : 
[ASP.NET MVC deployment in a form of distribution package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790184/asp-net-mvc-deployment-in-a-form-of-distribution-package)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the many suggestions in that post you linked to didn't help you? For instance, what is stopping you from trying to create an installer project, exactly?

Comment: You may create a executable program to set up your site into IIslS and also run the database script and make connections.

Comment: Are you trying to distribute something for developers or end users?

Comment: @JoshuaMorgan end users. But its not an actual commercial site. Its just a project I picked up myself to learn

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you want some way to deploy your website, database, configurations easily on your clients.

There are several ways to do this, but I believe the simplest one is to use the Web Deploy Package in Visual Studio.

Visual studio have One-Click publish options by using those options we can deploy / publish asp.net mvc web application to iis or server directly from visual studio.

We have different type of publish options available and one is the Web Deploy Package. If we select web deploy package method then a .zip package will be created in our local disk folder and you can use this package to deploy using CMD command prompt for example.

You can find a tutorial (step by step) [here](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-publish-with-web-deploy-package).